# line separator(LR) escape issue in json request body with WebClient

Tags: json, spring, graphql, escaping, spring-webclient

**I have a project about graphql (language is JAVA), in some json value I need to add the LF(\n) in the content.
If I add the "\n" in java code, the body written is \n. No escape here.**

WRITE: 273B POST /v1/graphql HTTP/1.1
user-agent: ReactorNetty/1.0.22
host: api.xxxx.com
Authorization: Bearer xxxxxxxx
Accept: application/json
Content-type: application/json
content-length: 894

WRITE: 894B {"query":"mutation {updateProduct(input: {..., description:\"ABC\nDEF\nGHI\", ... }){ product   { id } } }","variables":{},"operationName":null}

**ONCE I add the escaped one "\\n" in code and the body written from webclient is \\\\n. The double \\ is escaped...**

WRITE: 894B {"query":"mutation {updateProduct(input: {..., description:\"ABC\\\\nDEF\\\\nGHI\", ... }){ product   { id } } }","variables":{},"operationName":null}

**WHY??? I hope the written one is \\n as properly escaped.
It's a bug? Or I missed some setting about webclient?**

BTW, the client code is below (I'm using DGS framework also, but I think the issue is no related DGS)

`HttpClient httpClient = HttpClient.create().wiretap(this.getClass().getCanonicalName(),LogLevel.DEBUG,AdvancedByteBufFormat.TEXTUAL); this.client = new WebClientGraphQLClient(WebClient.builder().baseUrl(endpoint).clientConnector(new ReactorClientHttpConnector(httpClient)).defaultHeader("Authorization", StringUtils.join("Bearer", " ", key)).build());`

Comment: I don't understand why putting \n is a problem. Why are you using \\n? \n is a single character, \\n is 3, the two \ need escaping so \\\\n

Comment: Thank you John. If \n in json as request body like above, the graphql server side cant parse the json string and throw error like 'Syntax Error: Unterminated string', the reason aws the line separator \n in json string. 

You mean the server side should parse the json well instead of throwing error right? I'm not clear which side is fault, so I aksed the question. @JohnWilliams

Comment: BTW, I confirmed the behavior of server side. if the line separator in json value like \\n, the server side can parse it well and render it as a line separator when page rendering process.

Comment: https://github.com/Netflix/dgs-framework/issues/1407

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.